# IBM Liberty Server maximum parameters allowed per request Exception

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I am running Struts` version 2.3.1.2 on IBM Liberty Server version 18.0.0.2. I have a selectable datatable and when I try to select all the rows from table and try to export to excel I get the following exception.

Exception

> Exceeding maximum parameters allowed per request 10,000, current 10,000, cannot add more.

Before that application was deployed on WAS 8.5.5.x and we had this custom property: `"com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest": "-1"`. I can't find any configuration on Liberty.

I tried to add this in server.xml

[image]

The above com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxparamperequest="-1" works with was and doesnt work with liberty

Answer (score 0):

The same property can be set on Liberty via the `server.xml`:

`<webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxparamperrequest="-1"/>`

However, setting this property to -1 (unlimited) is not a good practice and can lead to excessive memory consumption.  A list of many of the supported `webContainer` properties can be found [here](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/#webContainer.html).

Comment: i tried it but the same error is coming